# How to represent the session switch from one node to other node? Will Sankey chart work?

Tags: info-visualisation, sankey, relationship

Folks,
Is it possible to create a sankey chart like the one attached using any libraries? Basically, I want to show how many sessions were steered/switched from one network to the other. D3js and Google Charts do not support cyclic representations. For example, If I want to show the session steered from A to B and vice versa, it is not supported by the libraries.

These are the concerns that I have:

1) Cyclic Representation
A -> B,
B -> A

2) Same nodes in Source and Destination
A   A
B   B
C   C

3) I want to color code each bands to differentiate the categories.

My design is based on this google chart, but modified it as per our requirement: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/sankey

If this is **not** doable, what are the other alternatives for visualizing the sessions that were steered from one node to the other?[image]

I've tried Chord diagram, but people feel that it is not readable.

TIA!

Comment: Are you specifically asking for frameworks that will allow you to visualise the node switching?

Comment: >If this is not doable, what are the other alternatives for visualizing the sessions that were steered from one node to the other?

Am looking for alternative representation because of the fact that the current proposal has implementation challenges. Had to elaborate it to give context.

Answer (score 2):

[D3 Sankey](https://github.com/d3/d3-sankey) and [D3 Sankey Diagram](https://github.com/ricklupton/d3-sankey-diagram) are two of several packages extending D3 with support for Sankey charts.  The latter appears to have the band coloring you're looking for.

Sankey charts by design eliminate cyclic structures by indexing.  The "C" in [A,C,B] is the same as in [B,C,A], but the "A" and "B" in the first are different from those in the second.

Having the same nodes in the destination probably requires fudging data for nodes which would not otherwise appear as sources or sinks, but this will vary with the implementation chosen.